# Tensorflow OneHotEncoder on large file for Linear Regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, tensorflow-datasets

I need to run a simple linear regression on a large dataset 30GB that can't be load in memory. The features are mostly categorical data. I've already build a prototype in scikit-learn that works just fine, but only works on a subsample of the data.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn import linear_model
data = pd.read_csv('datafile.csv', nrows=5e6)
""" data['categorical_feature'] it's a text field, which has categories comma separated. Example of structure is shown below.

   categorical_feature
1            1671,1293
2                 1293
3            1233,1671
"""
cat_vec = CountVectorizer(min_df=2)
m_cat = cat_vec.fit_transform(data['categorical_feature'])


lm = linear_model.Ridge()
lm.fit(m_cat, data['target'])
```

How would I write this in tensorflow? I've looked around didn't find much that can replicate the behaviour of [CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) in scikit-learn.

Comment: [`tf.one_hot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot)? You can use [`tf.data`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets) to work with bigger datasets or use [`tf.Transform`](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/transform/get_started) for more advanced setups.

Comment: Unfortunately, `tf.one_hot` requires the data to be already in individual category. Row 1 in my example below has two category (1671 and 1293). I'm not familiar with the other two - how does these fit to my use case?